# IdenityServer: API resources and scopes

Tags: identityserver4

My understanding is that a `Client` is allowed to access ome or more `ApiScope` and an `ApiScop` is linked to many `ApiResources` the names of which become the values of the audience claims.

I.e.,
1 client -> many API scopes
and
1 API scope -> many API resources

However, people talk about `ApiResources` having `ApiScopes` (not scopes having resources) which does not seem to be how the model works.

How is it supposed to work?
Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 3):

When you define an ApiResource, you add what ApiScopes it belongs to.

Like in this code, where Scopes below is tied to two ApiScopes.

```
var invoiceApi = new ApiResource()
{
    Name = "invoiceapi",
    Description = "This is the invoice Api-resource description",
    Enabled = true,
    DisplayName = "Invoice API Service",
    Scopes = new List<string> { "invoice", "manager" },
};
```

Also, do see my answer here:

[ApiResource vs ApiScope vs IdentityResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939)

To complement this answer, I write a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: So scopes have resources.

Comment: Yes, Scopes points out resources in IdentityServer

Comment: So why do people talk about resources having scopes (rather than scopes having resources)?