# Can't follow docs for Identity Server defining API resources and scopes

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I've designed my API resource as shown below (in accordance to e.g. [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437319/idenityserver-api-resources-and-scopes)). It works and acts as supposed to.

```
yield return new ApiResource("my_resource")
{
    Scopes = new string[]{ "my_scope" }
};
```

However, I just noticed that the above is wrong according to [the docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/api_resource.html#convenience-constructor-behavior), which baffles me. Apparently, it's supposed to be accepting an array of class `Scope`, not `string`.

```
yield return new ApiResource("my_wtf_resource")
{
    Scopes = { new Scope("my_wtf_scope") }
};
```

That produces an error telling me that it can't convert from `string` to `Scope`. Well, du'h... It gets even weirder as I discovered that there is actually a class `Scope` and it's located in the namespace `Microsoft.OpenApi.Writers`, which is suspiciously close to security, identity and such.

What's up wth that? Am I confusing something or have the docs people made a boo-boo?

Comment: You might have imported the wrong `ApiResource`. You need [the one in `IdentityServer4.Models`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/src/Storage/src/Models/ApiResource.cs#L87). There's also [one in `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities` namespace](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Entities/ApiResource.cs#L21).

Comment: @abdusco The only related import for `ApiResource` I have in the class is `using IdentityServer4.Models;`. Can you confirm explicitly that you have the field `Scopes` is of type `ICollection<Scope>` and not `ICollection<string>` as I do? This is weird...

Comment: I can't see any `List<Scope> Scopes` property in the codebase. Docs might be out of date.

Comment: Not sure where the official docs are source from, but in the repo, it states "list of scope names", i.e. string https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/docs/reference/api_resource.rst

Comment: @abdusco Ha! It certainly an act of aggression against myself in order to confuse me. I knew it... (Anyway, thanks for confirming that. I get so unsure when discrepancies like this pop up, always assuming it's me missing the point due to misfortune thinking. Feel free to summarize this as an answer to be accepted.)