# Identity: Propagating claims to downstream services

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I am trying to set up a distributed system with Duende-IdentityServer. In my architecture I am using a BFF (Backend For Front) as an API-GateWay for my client.

When my user is logged in using the BFF I want requests to propagate from the BFF to downstream services. (I am using GraphQL with stitching and schema federation, but I feel that might be irrelevant to the question.) Because I feel that it is important for the downstream services to be in control of the authorization of their data I would like claims received by the BFF to be forwarded to the downstream services. I figured something like attaching a JWT Bearer with the claims would work and was hoping that that way my downstream services wouldn't have to contact the identity server to validate the claims.

I tried a few things, but it is quite easy to get lost in the world that is OAuth2 and OIDC. I can't imagine my use case being that

Here is what I tried so far:

In the BFF:

```
//program.cs

 builder.Services.AddHttpClient(GraphQLSchemas.Identity, c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7500/graphql")).AddUserAccessTokenHandler();
 builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddRemoteSchemasFromRedis("GraphQL", sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ConnectionMultiplexer>())
            .ModifyOptions(x => x.RemoveUnreachableTypes = true);
services.AddBff();
   
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Bff-Cookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Bff-Cookie", options =>
    {
        // set session lifetime
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);

        // sliding or absolute
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;

        // host prefixed cookie name
        options.Cookie.Name = bffOptions.Cookie.Name ;
        options.Cookie.Domain = bffOptions.Cookie.Domain;

        // strict SameSite handling
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = bffOptions.IdentityServer.Host;

        // confidential client using code flow + PKCE
        options.ClientId = bffOptions.IdentityServer.ClientId;
      
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.ResponseMode = "query";

        options.MapInboundClaims = false;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        //options.
        // request scopes +refresh tokens
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        //options.Scope.Add("Administrator");
        options.Scope.Add("roles");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role;
    });
    /// code omitted for brevity
     app.UseBff();
```

If I log in on the bff these are the claims I get:
[image: Claims on bff]
However the access_token doesnt reflect this:
[image: Claims on access_token]

So when my HttpClient uses `.AddUserAccessTokenHandler();`
Only the access_token is passed to my downstream service:

```
//program.cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
             options.Authority = "https://localhost:7500";
             options.MapInboundClaims = false;

             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
             {
                 ValidateAudience = false,
                 ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" },

                 NameClaimType = "name",
                 RoleClaimType = "role"
             };
         });
  //code omitted for brevity
app.MapGraphQL().RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute
{
    AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
}).AllowAnonymous();
```

[image: Claims inside the downstream service]
But as you can see the Role claim etc is not passed.

How can receive the claims in in my downstream service? Preferably without reaching out to the identityserver. (Though it would be kinda nice if the downstream service could validate the jwt sent to it.

P.S. I also tried to follow 2 tutorials that create a ProfileService implementation, but for some reason when i register another profile service with the DI container the login through the bff fails and I havent been able to figure out why yet. A breakpoint in profile service would not be hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claims you see in .NET is the claims from the id_token or from the userinfo endpoint. They are separate from the ones found in the access token. You configure this in IdentityServer.

See my answer at [ApiResource vs ApiScope vs IdentityResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939) for more details about this.

So, the IdentityResource and ApiResource defines what claims can be returned for a given user. Then as this picture shows, those requested claims, are then looked up against the user database and the claims that is found in the database are then returned and used in the ID and access token.  as the picture from one of my training classes shows:

[image]

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: Thanks this is some much needed information. I will try this out.

Comment: Let me know if it works, and do check what is inside the ID and acccess token.

Comment: The idtoken is filled with the user claims. But your post set me on the right path is think

Comment: Thank you. im trying to get it all to work.  If i figure it out this will be accepted for sure. Thanks to you Ikind of understand the api resource vs Apiscope, but the tables in the ConfigurationDB from identity server kind of confuse me. How can i make sure the user has the correct permission to actually use the api scope?

Its so hard to find the right resources for this and most articles leave me with some more questions i wish i could just go in a discord server for an hour with someone to answer me all these questions. Id be willing to pay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248746/discussion-between-roxas-and-tore-nestenius).

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I never knew how use identityresources and api resources correctly. You definitely set me on the right path!

Comment: I added you Tore Nestinius, the name is Dylan

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Authentication is the concern of the gateway and authorization is Domain-specific and is related to downstream services (each one). JWT token should be validated and verified in the gateway and verification/validation process can be ignored in downstream services.

You can pass JWT headers (Authorization: Bearer bla) to the downstream services and they should ignore the validation like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        SignatureValidator = (jwt, tokenValidationParameters) =>
        {
            return new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(jwt);
        }
    };
});
```

this code makes all of your routes and HTTP  request flows to fullfil User object and its Claims and you can take action like this in your controllers:

```
//You will have claims in your User object even if you mark the action as anonymous.
//[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task Do() 
{
    this.User.HasClaim("bla")
}
```

**This is because of the protocol and Dotnet supports JWT out of the box** and I highly recommend you to forward JWT-formatted headers and do not change the token format/protocol for downstream services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might be missing something but i feel like your solution is waht i am doing already. The claims i need for authorization do not show up because they are not part of the access_token. How can I: a) Add them to the access token or: b) pass the id token instead and have that mapped to claims.

Comment: It depends on the size of your claims. If your token remains small, you can put them in the JWT otherwise you can use a hybrid solution of ProfileService and Caching (With expiration exactly equal to expiration of the token)

Comment: The claims will not be super big so i think i want them on my Jwt. Im just not sure how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "being sure how to do"? Just set minimal shortened meaningful names for your claims and put them inside the JWT token while creating on IdentityServer.