# IdentityServer4 always return 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

I am new to IdentityServer4. I have created a IdentityServer4 client, a scope at the IdentityServer4 running at https://localhost:44311/. I secured a sample Weather API using IdentityServer4. When I run `Program.cs`, I receive an Authorization token. I set this token using `client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);` but when I send GET request to API using  `await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44315/weatherforecast");`, I receive 401 **Unauthorized** or 403 **Forbidden**. What am I missing? Here is code:

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace weatherapi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.ApiName = "weatherapi";
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44311/";
                });

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**WeatherForecastController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace weatherapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using IdentityModel.Client;
using System.Text;

await SampleWeather();
//await SampleAdminApi();
async Task SampleWeather()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "https://localhost:44311/connect/token",
        ClientId = "weatherapi",
        ClientSecret = "weatherapi",
        Scope = "weatherapi_scope",
        GrantType = "client_credentials"
    });

    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get token", tokenResponse.Exception);
    }

    client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

    var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44315/weatherforecast");
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems to be a plain API, I would replace AddIdentityServerAuthentication with AddJwtBearer (see this [page](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/apis/aspnetcore/jwt/))

I would also set this flag to true inside AddJWtBearer

```
opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

Because then you would get some more details in the WWW-Authenticate header that you get back when you get a 401 error, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: `AddJwtBearer` does solve the problem. But I am bound to use `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` as I am actually calling IdentityServer4 Admin APIs. I am building a custom user interface using IdentityServer4 Admin APIs but I am getting 403 Forbidden. Also I can not use options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

Comment: I checked `Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.csproj` and it is using `AddJwtBearer`. I added `options.IncludeErrorDetails= true;` but I do not see any error details in the response headers

---- `services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;      }).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { options.IncludeErrorDetails= true; });`

Comment: IF you get a 401 and if the JwtBearer handler handles it, then you should see a WWW-Authenticate header

Comment: I am getting 403 Forbidden. When I use Admin API using swagger, it works but from C# it gives 403 Forbidden although I am getting a Bearer token.

Comment: 403 means authorization error, I guess your access token lacks some claim that your API requires. I would check the API logs for details why the request fails.

Comment: I do not see any errors in log. I do not know how to add claims or find missing claims. Here is the token that fails:

{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "BDA1EEDC63CBEC4687D937C58B3FAB61",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}.{
  "nbf": 1674458016,
  "exp": 1674461616,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44311",
  "aud": "skoruba_identity_admin_api",
  "client_id": "skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
  "jti": "F8EE7CF9CECCEF5A9AF1E639F4C3366C",
  "iat": 1674458016,
  "scope": [
    "skoruba_identity_admin_api"
  ]
}.[Signature]

Comment: Step #1, is to configure IdentityServer to include the desired claims in the access token, you do that by adding ApiScope and ApiResoures, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939