# IdentityServer: Scope openid not found in store or not supported by requested resource indicators

Tags: c#, authorization, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

I'm requesting GET following [this example](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/endpoints/authorize/). In my case, it's this.

> GET /connect/authorize?
> client_id=tyr-idp&
> scope=openid&
> response_type=code&
> redirect_uri=https://localhost_4200/login&
> state=check123

The client has grant type set to *authorization_code* (also, the redirect URI is set and the client secret requirement is deactivated). I've added the scope *oidc* to the client's claims and created an identity resource with the name *oidc* too (as discussed in [this article](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/resources/identity/)).

`select * from IdentityResources` produces a single line with columns `Scope` being *oidc* and `ClientId` being *13* (which is the client's ID). I also added claims to the resource: the default *sub* to the first one and a few custom ones to the others.

For some reason, the log shows that Duende can't connect that scope to my request and give me the following error. Creating additional identity resources (and requesting them under *scope*) produces one error message per each, stating the equivalent problem that it's not found or supported.

> Scope openid not found in store or not supported by requested resource indicators.

Executing the following, shows that there are two scopes with the expected names and values.

```
Client client = context.Clients
  .Include(a=>a.AllowedGrantTypes)
  .Include(a=>a.AllowedScopes)
  .Include(a=>a.RedirectUris)
  .First(a => a.ClientId == "tyr-idp");
```

Googling the issue produced nothing I recognized as useful. I'm also thorn between the dual root causes mentioned: is it because I haven't declared the scope correctly or is it because I haven't connect it properly?

Not sure how to troubleshoot it further.

[image]

[image]

I also tried to manually put in a new client into the context with the same, failing outcome.

```
Client client = new()
{
  ClientId = "client_id",
  ClientName = "client_name",
  RequireClientSecret = false,
  RequirePkce = false,
  AllowOfflineAccess = true,
  AllowedGrantTypes = new(){ new(){ GrantType = "authorization_code" }},
  AllowedScopes = new(){ new() { Scope = "openid" } , new() { Scope = "oidc" } },
  RedirectUris = new(){ new(){ RedirectUri = "https://localhost:4200/login" } }
};
context.Clients.Add(client);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit**

The request

> GET /connect/authorize?client_id=tyr-idp&scope=tyr-trifecta&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7101/spa

The client scopes

[image]

The API resources

[image]

The ID resources

[image]

Comment: Can I please see the `List<IdentityResource>` you've defined in code? And the `AllowedScopes` that you've defined when creating the `Client` object for `tyr-idp`?

Comment: I believe you're defining `oidc` and not `openid` as a claim which I believe is what the issue is here. Asking for `scope=openid&` means you must have a scope with the name `openid` defined - is there a particular reason why your scope is called `oidc`?.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks for the good questions. I don't declare the clients/scopes in the code. Instead, I have stored them in the DB. I have tried both *oidc* and *openid* as the name of the scope (both are present in the table `IdentityResources` and connected to the client in `ClientScopes` in my DB). Of course, both have the claim of `sub` connected to them. I'll post a screenie from the object while executing.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I simply fail to understand how it can be in the DB, present in the client object, yet, not recognized when hitting */connect/authorize* endpoint. It seems like it should work but I'm missing some tiny detail, formality or such. After two days of struggling, I'm out of ammo...

Comment: Can you recreate the request you're doing to `/connect/authorize` in `curl` or `wget` and share the command + the full output? Please also share the relative full data dump of the `ClientScopes` and `IdentityResources` tables.

Comment: have you configured the various resources correctly? see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939

Comment: @ToreNestenius I'm convinced that so it's the case. What you made me realize is that when I request a scope being an API resource, I get the hit on my */account/login* method. So, for some reason, the ID resources aren't present. For now, it actually's sufficient for me because I'm at the stage of obtaining the code that will be exchanged for a token. I'm stuck on [step 4-5](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow) (I'm on Duende but it's the same flow). I can't remember how I routed the entered user name back to the Authority.

Comment: I do have a bunch of troubleshooting blog posts here https://nestenius.se/ 

APIResources and APIScopes are meant to control what goes inside the access token, not ID-token. 

you need to break down the problem into two phases, 1. getting the id-access token using AddOpenIDConnect , 2. using the access token with AddJwtBearer. 
Where is your problem?

Comment: @ToreNestenius Yes Tore, I'm well familiar with your posts. They save my butt numerous times and I still claim that I owe you a large pizza once in Skåne. Sadly, I'm stuck in Fjolleträsk so you'll have to wait. Now, as per your question - it's neither. I seem to get stuck on obtaining the code, prior to any tokens. It's kind of retarded because I've done that several times before. Somehow, I can't figure it out now. I'll probably ask another question and once *that one* is resolved, get back here (if still needed).

Comment: @KonradViltersten If you can please answer my question above, we can help. You're not even getting an auth code yet. I don't see how ID or access tokens are relevant here.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Or am I to understand that even the initial request, only resulting in a code to exchange should be able to use scopes from ID resources and not only API resources?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes, I was preparing that too. I'll post it as an edit to the question and then ping you.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary **STOP!** You just broke the problem. Unknowingly. But still. The script I'm running to recreate the DB had a "1" not "0" for enabled scopes. But during hours of fighting I must have accidentally changed that to "0" when I executed `update IdentityResources set Enabled = 0` and forgot to add `where ...`. The issue is gone. You can post an answer to be accepted or I will. Great (but convoluted) troubleshooting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Hey hey, I might know a thing or two...  glad you got it sorted. I think you also mean it had a `0` not a `1`.

Comment: @Konrad, ps, your link to https://www.kentor.se/is broken in your profile :-)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Well, it **had had** *1*, which then was changed sloppily so it **became** *0*, which it **had** until I changed it so it **came to have** *1* again (at which point the screenie was taken. (God, I love English tempus grammar!) Now, I'll ask a new question on the code not being returned and also update the link in my profile. Tore had good eyes, there. I left the company years ago and they were bought by another one, too...

Comment: @ToreNestenius So, the code thing I'm trying to obtain - [here's the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122659/code-not-returned-on-auth-code-flow-in-duende-return-back-to-login-endpoint-ins) if you're still up for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments.

[`IdentityResource`](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/identity_resource/) in the `IdentityResources` table was accidentally set to be disabled (`0`) for the `openid` scope, preventing it from being used as a valid (and required in this case) `scope` parameter.

Changing it to be enabled (`1`) fixes the issue.

Comment: Right. Good job! Also, now that this embarrassing thing is killed, [here's the actual issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122659/code-not-returned-on-auth-code-flow-in-duende-return-back-to-login-endpoint-ins) that I'm trying to accomplish (getting the code from the authority. Feel free to take a whack if you have time.